# Sorting floating points from file in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, sorting, structure

Right, so after many attempts i have finally got some code that can take integer values from file, and sort them next to their respective names.

For example:

User file____________  Score file___________--

```
User1              4
User2              6 
User3              2
User4              3
```

My program has the ability to sort the score file into a descending order, while keeping the first intact.

This produces:

```
User2               6
User1               4
User4               3
User3               2
```

Now, this isn't my problem, the code functions perfectly. However, as an extended assignment. the scores are now floating points.

My inital thinking was: Easy, Just change all the score integer variables into floats. That works, except it doesn't sort them after the decimal place.

Rather than give the "Dumb" code, i'm going to give the perfect code and mark my changes.

```
 #include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
 #include <stdlib.h>     /* qsort */

struct Element
{
    int userId;
    int score;
};

int ascendingSortCompareFunction (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return (((struct Element *)a)->score - ((struct Element *)b)->score);
}

int descendingSortCompareFunction (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return -ascendingSortCompareFunction(a, b);
}

void readFromFile(const char *const filename,  struct Element **elements, size_t *count)
{
FILE *file;
void *auxiliary;
int   index;
int   score;
char  line[512];

if ((elements == NULL) || (count == NULL))
    return;
*elements = NULL;
file      = fopen("TIStotS.txt", "r");
if (file == NULL)
    return;

index = 0;
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL)
{
    if (sscanf(line, "%d", &score) == 1)
    {                //^^Changed to %f
        auxiliary = realloc(*elements, (1 + *count) * sizeof(struct Element));
        if (auxiliary == NULL)
        {
            free(*elements);
            fclose(file);

            *elements = NULL;

            return;
        }
        *elements                  = auxiliary;
        (*elements)[*count].userId = 1 + index;
        (*elements)[*count].score  = score;

        *count += 1;
        index  += 1;
    }
}
fclose(file);
}

int main ()
{
size_t          count;
size_t          n;
struct Element *elements;
size_t          size;

elements = NULL;
size     = sizeof(struct Element);
count    = 0;

readFromFile("TIStotS.txt", &elements, &count);
if ((elements != NULL) && (count > 0))
{
    qsort(elements, count, size, descendingSortCompareFunction);
    printf ("UserID\tScore (Descending Sort)\n");

    for (n = 0 ; n < count ; n++)
    {

    int end, loop, line;
    char str[512];

    FILE *fd = fopen("PDfirstN.txt", "r");
    if (fd == NULL) 
    {
         printf("Failed to open file\n");
         getch();
     }
line=elements[n].userId;

for(end = loop = 0;loop<line;++loop){
    if(0==fgets(str, sizeof(str), fd)){//include '\n'
        end = 1;//can't input (EOF)
        break;
    }
}
if(!end)
printf("%s",str);
printf("%d\n",elements[n].score);
     //^^ changed to %.2f
fclose(fd);


    }
    free(elements);
}
getchar();

return 0;
}
```

This gives the code for integer sorting, when i change all score variables from %d to %f., it sorts in file like:

```
  4.23
  3.75
  3.78
  3.23
  2.25
```

Where the values are not sorted correctly, and only done to their first significant figure

Edit: I have already turned int score into float score etc, it doesn't fix the sort

Comment: int score; should be double/float

Comment: For the other sort problem, in the question where you use command line `sort` the solution is to add more fields to the `struct` and then write the aproppriate comparison functions using `strcmp` for strings. BTW, did you ask that question as another user?

Comment: @iharob Nope i stole his answer

Answer (score 4):

You need also to change the datatypes (of score variables and fields) from `int`s to `double`s

BTW, several compilers are able to warn you about that mistake (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) if compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) on `scanf`

Answer (score 2):

Change the score variable type to `float`.

```
struct Element
{
    int userId;
    float score; /* instead of int score;
};
```

and here

```
int   index;
float score; /* instead of int score; */
char  line[512];
```

and finally

```
if (sscanf(line, "%f", &score) == 1) /* instead of if (sscanf(line, "%d", &score) == 1) */
```

And fix the compare functions

```
if (((struct Element *)a)->score == ((struct Element *)b)->score)
    return 0;
return (((struct Element *)a)->score < ((struct Element *)b)->score) ? -1 : 1
```

by not changing the type of the `score` member and `score` variable passed to `scanf` the value was truncated making `3.75` and `3.78` -> `3 == 3` when truncated, and hence the sort order you observed.

Comment: Changing the comparison functions to return floats is incorrect.  The definition of the comparison function passed to `qsort()` is  `int (*compar)(const void*,const void*)` - it should return an `int` representing the result of the comparison.  See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/.

Comment: @frasnian what was I thiking... You are absolutely right.